# Manipulate the method sum() in the method average()

Tags: java

I have an array below:

```
int[] tab = {10,4,23,45,28,34,89,9,16,55};
```

My method sum() works correctly:

```
public static int sum(int[] array){
      int sum_array = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        sum_array += array[i];
      }
      return sum_array;
    }
```

Now, I would like to create a method `average()` by adding the method `sum()`.

I have this for now:

```
public static float average(int[] tab){
      return sum[tab] / length[tab];
}
```

My error message is:

```
Main.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
      return sum[tab] / length[tab];
```

I don't understand the problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `sum[tab]` and `length[tab]` are invalid, since `sum` and `length` are not arrays.

It should be:

```
public static float average(int[] tab){
    return sum(tab) / tab.length;
}
```

Note that this will return a whole number (`int`) cast to `float`, since you are dividing two `int`s.

If you wish the result to be more accurate (i.e. including fractions), you should perform floating point division, by casting one of the operands to `float`:

```
public static float average(int[] tab){
      return (float) sum(tab) / tab.length;
}
```

Comment: Return result need to cast float.